# RecordType not returning results

Tags: record-type

I am trying to access the Recordtype field on the Call object but when I run that field through a query (in this case the getPicklistValueLabels method) I receive the following error:

> getPicklistValueLabels called with field that cannot be accessed: RecordType

Does anyone know why this might be happening? We are able to access other Salesforce Standard fields.

Answer (score 2):

You should use either SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos() (see [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm)) or query the [RecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) object.

```
for(RecordTypeInfo info: Call.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()) {
  options.add(new SelectOption(info.getRecordTypeId(), info.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Record Type is different than other fields it's not really a picklist so your method would not work.

In all my happenings every time I needed to get information about the record type I had to query for it.

Example:

```
List<RecordType> recordTypeAcc = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'Dan_Account'];
```